# Java POST application/json

Tags: java, json, spring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [POST request via RestTemplate in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json)

So, I'm trying to do a cURL code POST with API (using spring). The problem is that I've tried 3 different ways but none of them have worked. I got a 412 error.

Here is the cURL code:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-X POST -u user:password -d '{ "external_id":"PES001", "name":"João da Silva",   "email":"joao@empresa.com.br", "login":"joao@empresa.com.br", "password":"123456", "phone _number":"555199999999" }' https://xxxxxxxxx
```

Here is my java code:

```
HttpHeaders createHeaders( )
{
    return new HttpHeaders()
    {
        {
            String auth = "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxx" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxx";
            byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encode(
                                     auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
            String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );
            set( "Authorization", authHeader );
        }
    };
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/createuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String>  sendCreateUser()
{

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    //      HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    //              DefaultHttpClient httpClient =
    //          (DefaultHttpClient) requestFactory.getHttpClient();
    //              httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
    //          new AuthScope("https://xxxxxxxxx",443, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
    //          new UsernamePasswordCredentials("xxxxx", "xxxxxx"));

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = createHeaders();

    List<MediaType> acceptableMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType>();
    acceptableMediaTypes.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.setAccept(acceptableMediaTypes);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);


    // restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    // handler para controlar as requisições
    //  restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new UmovErrorHandler());

    List<String> criarValor = new ArrayList<String>();
    criarValor.add("external_id : TST5");
    criarValor.add("name : Teste5");
    criarValor.add("email : teste5@empresa.com.br");
    criarValor.add("login : teste5@empresa.com.br");
    criarValor.add("password : 123456");
    criarValor.add("phone_number : 555199999995");

    MultiValueMap<String, String> values = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    values.put("data", criarValor);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
    String outputBytes = "{'external_id': 'TST5644235',  'name': 'Test5443435e5',  'email': 't5454este43435@empresa.com.br',  'login': 'teste54545@empresa.com.br',  'password': '1234545456',  'phone_number': '555545199999995'}";
    map.add("data", outputBytes);
    //      map.add("external_id","TST5");
    //      map.add("name","Teste5");
    //      map.add("email","teste5@empresa.com.br");
    //      map.add("login","teste5@empresa.com.br");
    //      map.add("password","123456");
    //      map.add("phone_number","555199999995");

    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, httpHeaders);

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter teste = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();

    messageConverters.add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);


    String teste22 =  restTemplate.postForObject("https://xxxxxxxxx", request, String.class);
    String test32 = null;

    //  integrationService.putSendPlanejamento(osOperacao);
    return null;
}
```

AS you con see, all the 3 ways I've tried are listed in this code.
Can someone please help me ?

Comment: so curl works, but java doesn't?

Comment: Do you know what a 412 http response code means and in what situations your webserver responds that way? I suspect the call never reaches your code.