# GET request in RestTemplate in JSON

Tags: java, spring, http, get, resttemplate

It's been troubling for a couple days already for a seemingly super straightforward question:

I'm making a simple GET request using RestTemplate in `application/json`, but I keep getting

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:636)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:592)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:552)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:470)
```

I did research and followed this [tutorial](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-android/1.0.x/reference/html/rest-template.html), also I looked at solutions from this [POST request via RestTemplate in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json/4077502#4077502). But none of them helped, here's my code:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();    
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestHeaders);
restTemplate.exchange(endpoint, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

`endpoint` is `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items?itemIds=" + URLEncoder.encode(itemIds, "UTF-8")` which works fine in Postman.
`itemIds` is a comma-separated list like below:

`5400028914,5400029138,5400029138,5400029138,5400029138,5400028401,5400028918,5400028076,5400028726`

I also tried to use `getForObject` like below:

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(endpoint, String.class);
```

which gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

I'm not sure what I missed or did wrong, but the same endpoint works perfectly on Postman, but the only difference is that I added Content-Type header in Postman app.

This is my Request from Postman:

`GET /api/v1/items?itemIds=abc%2cdef%2cghi HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Postman-Token: 84790e06-86aa-fa8a-1047-238d6c931a68
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4`

So how can I correctly set content-type using RestTemplate if my above code is wrong?

Another deep dive, I've fired up [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the two HTTP requests, here are the screenshots:

The request from Postman: [image: request from Postman]

The request from my Java code: [image: request from Java program]

I still don't see why the one from my Java program throws 400 while the one from Postman works fine.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you try getForObject() and getForEntity()?  they may be better in your case than exchange().

Comment: Dump the request you're sending through postman and post it here.

Comment: But why are you using content-type for GET request? Content type is "The MIME type of the body of the request (used with POST and PUT requests)." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: Sure, I tried getForObject(), see my edits to original post. I'll try getForEntity also. @zakariaamine

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. @VladBochenin, but in this case, how can I specifiy its content-type? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to specify result which you are waiting for from server, you should use Accept header

Comment: probably the client has rejected the request saying unsupported media type then show us the content type consumed by the client? so that we can set it accordingly. Also try using MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE

Comment: Sure, I also tried this `requestHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));` which resulted in 400 also.

Comment: I've added my request from Postman in my original post. thanks. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: @FisherCoder What version of Spring you are using? are you using boot ?

Comment: The latest stable version of Spring: 4.2.0, not Spring Boot

Comment: @all, I've just captured the two requests using Wireshark and updated my original post with screenshots.

Comment: @FisherCoder Do you have jackson-databind in your classpath ? can try including it ?

Comment: No, I don't. The problem was encoding issue. Please see my answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, eventually, one of my co-workers helped me figure out why, believe it or not, it's this simple:

The `endpoint` was like this:
`"http:localhost:8080/api/v1/items?itemIds=" + URLEncoder.encode(itemIds, "UTF-8");`

However, it should be `"http:localhost:8080/api/v1/items?itemIds=" + itemIds;`

`itemIds` is just a comma-separated list.

After URLEncoder encoding via "UTF-8" schema, this comma-separated list becomes `itemIds=5400028914%2C5400029138%2C5400029138%2C5400029138%2C5400029138%2C5400028401%2C5400028918%2C5400028076`

from

`itemIds=5400028914,5400029138,5400029138,5400029138,5400029138,5400028401,5400028918,5400028076,5400028726`

We don't need to URLEncoder to encode the URL when using RestTemplate, anyone could help me deepen my understanding here please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

***You don't need set "requestEntity" for a GET method, try your code like this:***

```
public ItemInfo getItemInfo() throws Exception {
    String url =
            "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items?itemIds=abc";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();     
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
    String responseBody = response.getBody();
    handlerError(response, url);
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, ItemInfo.class);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to send REST request", exception);
        throw new Exception(ErrorCode.NOT_AVAILABLE, url);
    }
}

private void handlerError(final ResponseEntity<String> response, final String url) throws Exception {
    String responseBody = response.getBody();
    try {
        if (RestUtil.isError(response.getStatusCode())) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            MyInfoError myInfoError = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, MyInfoError.class);
            throw new Exception(infoErreur, ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_CODE_ERROR);
        } else if (RestUtil.isNotFound(response.getStatusCode())) {
            throw new Exception(ErrorCode.NOT_AVAILABLE, "MyService");
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        LOGGER.error("failed to send REST request", exception);
        throw new Exception(ErrorCode.NOT_AVAILABLE, url);
    }
}
```

**I put it NULL because GET method not send any JSON request body/headers:**

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

**OR: put your headers in GET method like this:**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, String.class);
```

***For Example for POST you need to set requestEntity like below:***

```
ItemFormRequest request =
            new ItemFormRequest(1,"item no", "item name");
HttpEntity<ItemFormRequest> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
        String responseBody = response.getBody();
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Their `HttpEntity` has no body. It's intended simply as a container for the headers in this case.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed my answer because it's getting late here and I was lack some question information  :)

Thank you @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Your code is now equivalent to theirs so I don't understand the purpose of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.