# How send post data (json format) using spirng restTemplate

Tags: java, rest, resttemplate, form-parameter

I want to post data like this:
[image]

is that posible using resttemplate ?

Comment: Have you checked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST request via RestTemplate in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json)