# integration test spring restTemplate (POST --> pass List<String> and receive List<Object>)

Tags: spring, testing, resttemplate

I want to test method of receiving a list of objects, according to list of given strings. 
My original method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fil/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<List<Tag>> findAllByCpe(@RequestBody Fil fil) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(tagRepository.findAllBy(fil));
}
```

Query (tagRepository):

```
 @Query("SELECT t FROM Tag t WHERE (t.cpe IS NULL OR t.cpe IN (:#{#fil.cpes}))")
    List<Tag> findAllBy(@Param("fil") Fil fil);
```

Fil (Class holding a list of strings I want to search by)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Fil {

    public Fil() {

    }

    @NotNull
    private List<String> cpes;

}
```

I wrote an integration test:

```
@Test
public void FindTagGivenListOfCpes() {
    //GIVEN
    List<String> cpes = new ArrayList<>();
    cpes .add("C1");
    cpes .add("C2");
    cpes .add("C3");

    List<Tag> tagList = (List<Tag>) tagTestBuilder
        .saved()
        .itemList()
        .build();

    //WHEN
    ResponseEntity<Tag[]> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(TagsResourceConstants.PATH + "/fil/", cpes, Tag[].class);


    //THEN
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatusCodeValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 415 means: Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload format is in an unsupported format ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415)).

You need to provide the information on requested content type and expected response format.

Spring defaults to content-type header to application/json. 
So you need to tell your server that it should use json to de-serilze Tag class on post request, or specify the required type on the post request.
e.g 
org.springframework.http.MediaType#APPLICATION_XML_VALUE or org.springframework.http.MediaType#APPLICATION_JSON

You will have a similar issue on response.

You can find an example on how to change restTemplate conntent type here
[POST request via RestTemplate in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json)

I suggest reading:
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping
http://www.baeldung.com/rest-template

Comment: I googled that, but that doesn't ring any bell of how to applied that information to the test. Thanks for the source tho - I will read it. I think my mistake is that I should link my "input"-cpe with the response (tag). But have no idea how to do this :/

Comment: Could you share some more details like spring versions. Subset of the project on GitHub will be the best

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I didnt implement fil to create a list of objects. 
I should use:

```
Fil fil= new Fil();
fil.setCpes(Stream.of("cpe1").collect(Collectors.toList()));
```