# How to correctly pass body to spring rest template?

Tags: spring, kotlin, resttemplate

SOLUTION: The API endpoint to get this specific information is the only one different from all the other ones. Thus I was trying to contact an outdated one.

Everything described in the post works like a charm.

---

Using kotlin and spring, I want to send a POST request to an API.

This is a curl, generated via postman, that works correctly:

```
curl --location --request POST 'URL' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username":"username",
    "password":"password"
}'
```

However, with spring + rest template using the following code, it seems that the body is not parsed correctly, as the API I am contacting sends me back a 401, that occurs when password/username provided are incorrect/missing.

```
val body = JwtQuery(getUsername(), getPassword())
return restTemplate.postForObject(url, body, Jwt::class.java)!!
```

This is the JwtQuery class:

```
data class JwtQuery (
        val username: String,
        val password: String
)
```

Note that `getUsername()` and `getPassword()` return the expected value.

What am I doing wrong ?

---

Edit 1: setting headers

Using:

```
val body = JwtQuery(getUsername(), getPassword())
val headers = HttpHeaders()
headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
val bodyEntity = HttpEntity(body, headers)
return restTemplate.postForObject(url, bodyEntity, Jwt::class.java)!!
```

Still returns the same error (401)

---

edit 2: marshaled JwtQuery

```
val body = JwtQuery(mesProperties.getUsername(), mesProperties.getPassword())
val marshaled = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(body)
println(marshaled)
```

Output:
{"username":"username","password":"password"}

Comment: Have you tried setting the correct HTTP header (e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json)?

Comment: @Smutje I edited the question. Same problem with headers

Comment: OK, and when you marshall objects of type `JwtQuery` you get the same structure as you passed in via `--data-raw`?

Comment: @Smutje How can I check that ?

Comment: Assuming you use Spring and have access to Jackson: `String marshaled = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new JwtQuery(getUsername(), getPassword()));`

Comment: @Smutje edited question with result. It is the same.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem did not lie where it appeared in the first place.