# how to send messages to Teams using JAVA and Microsoft graph API

Tags: java, spring, rest, microsoft-graph-api

Im trying to send message to MS Team through JAVA . MS Team exposes the POST API through MS Graph which we can use to send messages to Teams channel using teams ID and channel ID . This what I understood from doc  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk

There are two codes which I have written . none of them are working

**CODE 1**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<team id>/channels/<channel id>/messages";     
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            String requestJson = "{\"queriedQuestion\":\"Is there pain in your hand?\"}";
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.setBearerAuth("token");  
                
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestJson, headers);
            String answer = restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
            System.out.println(answer);

    }
```

error coming is :

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest:
> 400 Bad Request: "{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Missing
> body
> content","innerError":{"date":"2023-06-22T07:44:37","request-id":"dc287932-45c4-4940-8f23-c717cb5d6e09","client-request-id":"dc287932-45c4-4940-8f23-c717cb5d6e09"}}}"
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:915)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:481)
> at oe.kubeapi.cloudcontroller.TeamMes4.main(TeamMes4.java:36)

**CODE 2**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("Hello World 3", headers);
    
        headers.setBearerAuth("token");
        headers.add("Header", "header1");
        
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<team id>/channels/<channel id>/messages");
        
        HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                builder.toUriString(), 
                HttpMethod.POST,
                entity, 
                String.class);
    }
```

error coming is :

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest:
> 400 Bad Request: "{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to
> read JSON request payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set
> and payload is of valid JSON
> format.","innerError":{"date":"2023-06-22T07:52:21","request-id":"229cc590-dcdf-47ed-89cf-e47ddf136be7","client-request-id":"229cc590-dcdf-47ed-89cf-e47ddf136be7"}}}"
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:915)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:864)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:764)
> at
> org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:646)
> at oe.kubeapi.cloudcontroller.TeamMessage1.main(TeamMessage1.java:33)

I truly don't understand what is the issue. I searched lot and modified the code accordingly . I referred this question also : [POST request via RestTemplate in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075991/post-request-via-resttemplate-in-json)

please suggest

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java) is the documentation page of the endpoint you invoke.

The error message of your first try is

> Missing body content

The complaint claims that you did not properly define the body content, which is good news in the sense that you were able to request the endpoint you wanted after all and you are pretty close to make it work.

[image]

So, you need to represent a [chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-1.0) object in JSON format. Something like this:

```
{
  "attachments": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessageAttachment"}],
  "body": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.itemBody"},
  "channelIdentity": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.channelIdentity"},
  "chatId": "String",
  "createdDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "deletedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "etag": "String",
  "eventDetail": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.eventMessageDetail"},
  "from": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessageFromIdentitySet"},
  "id": "String (identifier)",
  "importance": "String",
  "lastEditedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "String (timestamp)",
  "locale": "String",
  "mentions": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessageMention"}],
  "messageHistory": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessageHistoryItem"}],
  "messageType": "String",
  "policyViolation": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessagePolicyViolation"},
  "reactions": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.chatMessageReaction"}],
  "replyToId": "String (identifier)",
  "subject": "String",
  "summary": "String",
  "webUrl": "String"
}
```

Example taken from the documentation:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
ItemBody body = new ItemBody();
body.content = "Hello World";
chatMessage.body = body;

graphClient.teams("fbe2bf47-16c8-47cf-b4a5-4b9b187c508b").channels("19:4a95f7d8db4c4e7fae857bcebe0623e6@thread.tacv2").messages()
    .buildRequest()
    .post(chatMessage);
```

Notice that a `ChatMessage` object is being created and an `ItemBody` is being assigned to its `body` member. Also notice the use of `GraphServiceClient`.

Comment: Thanks . I have seen this doc already , but the issue is , they dont have any example of passing the bearer token to graphClient . 
I have the bearer token generated from Auth code provider

Comment: @user2315104 is this page helpful? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/issues/961